# I keep getting an error when I install Gnuplot with Homebrew in order to use Octave

Tags: xcode, gnuplot, octave, x11, xquartz

I am having a problem whenever I install Gnuplot with Homebrew on OS X. Right now, I am able to do:

```
brew install gnuplot
```

and it works. However, running Octave afterwards still tells me that my "terminal is set to 'unknown'" whether octaverc is:

```
setenv("GNUTERM","X11")
```

or

```
setenv("GNUTERM","qt")
```

I tried doing `brew install gnuplot --with-x11`

and it doesn't work. In fact, this is what it tells me.

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/MyUsername/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gnuplot/01.configure:
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: exec: /usr/bin/sed: cannot execute: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: exec: /usr/bin/sed: cannot execute: No such file or directory
checking whether the C compiler works... /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: exec: /usr/bin/sed: cannot execute: No such file or directory
no
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: exec: /usr/bin/sed: cannot execute: No such file or directory
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/gnuplot20151008-1604-naulq5/gnuplot-5.0.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: exec: /usr/bin/sed: cannot execute: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: line 7: exec: /usr/bin/sed: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

and I have absolutely no idea what this means or how to fix it.

If you need any more information I'll give it to you but I don't know what else I can give

EDIT 1: According to one of the comments, my /usr/bin/sed doesn't exist (and I guess isn't an executable while we're at it). How do I go about getting this thing to exist and be an executable? Ok, so my sed directory exists, but it's in `/usr/local/bin/sed` and not `/usr/bin/sed`. How do I go about fixing this or making Homebrew look in a different place?

EDIT 2: I've ran `brew doctor` and it tells me that I have some unbrewed dylibs, header files, and static libraries. I don't know how to go about fixing this.

Comment: (a) I guess you're running it from an XQuartz terminal and not the regular Mac terminal? (b) If so, have you tried running it from a new terminal? (I've noticed that w/some programs certain variables don't get updated in the old terminal.)

Comment: I have tried running in both terminals. Neither of them worked.

Comment: you did check `ls -l  /usr/bin/sed` to confirm it exists, and marked as excutable? Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't exist. What do I do to fix this ?

Comment: You might consider running `brew doctor`. I've resolved issues with that in the past.

Comment: ...or `brew install sed` first, if you haven't tried that

Comment: `brew install sed` does nothing. `brew install gnu-sed` does something, but does not fix my problem at all.

Comment: I'm not sure about dir structure in OSX, but try `which sed`. Maybe it is only in `/bin`. If so, you can make a hard link or pass a config param to `brew` to tell it to look in `/bin/`. If not in `/bin` then I think there is something fundamentally wrong with your base install, as `sed` should be in one of those 2 dirs (at least in any *nix variant I know). Good luck!

Comment: My sed exists in usr/local/bin/sed. How do I go about making a hard link or passing a config param to brew?

Comment: please move that important information and question to the top of your question. Then we can delete all of these comments. (Sorry, I'm not a brew person, but you could use google search to find that info. Same for hard links.) Good luck.